# How to see request domain in JAVA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dns, server

I have a JAVA application accessible via DNS by beta.myapp.com and www.myapp.com

I would like to be able to know, In my controller, if I come from the first or the second.

I tried

```
String domain = request.getRequestURL().toString();     
String localAdd = request.getLocalAddr();
String localName = request.getLocalName();
String serverName = request.getServerName();
String inetCano = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
```

But it gave me

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
127.0.0.1 localhost 
0.0.0.0 
www.server-name-but-not-DNS-one.com
""
```

How can I access the URL actually wrote by the user?

Thanks

Comment: you can try with request.getHeader("referer")

Comment: It s not working : the referer is null when i do a Ctrl F5 for example

Answer (score 5):

The domain is available in **Host** **header** of HTTP request:

```
request.getHeader("Host");
```